# Deserialization does not work for all nodes using Newtonsoft Json

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft.Json for the deserialization of a JSON string, found [here](https://www.umweltbundesamt.de/api/air_data/v2/measures/json?date_from=2020-01-01&date_to=2020-01-05&time_from=1&time_to=24&component=1&scope=1).
After deserialization, I see only 53 of the expected 480 nodes from the JSON-string in my data-object.  What am I doing wrong?

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(ReceiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    String content = sr.ReadToEnd();

    //var results = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(content);
    var file = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(content);
    var data = file["data"];
    foreach (var station in data)
    {
        foreach (var date in station)
        {
            string s_station = date.Path.ToString();
            s_station = s_station.Replace("data.", "");
            int s_station_int = Convert.ToInt32(s_station);

            foreach (var line in date)
            {
                var values = line.First;
                string component_id = values[0].ToString();
                string scope_id = values[1].ToString();
                string value = values[2].ToString();
                string date_end = values[3].ToString();
                string index_qual = values[4].ToString();

                double value_dbl = Convert.ToDouble(value);
                double index_qual_dbl = Convert.ToDouble(index_qual);
                int component_id_int = Convert.ToInt32(component_id);
                int scope_id_int = Convert.ToInt32(scope_id);

                UBA_values_List.Add(new UBADE_air_values_obj(date_end, component_id_int, scope_id_int, value_dbl, index_qual_dbl, s_station_int));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't help without having a json and data object

Comment: ..this is the string for the WebRequest to get the json respons:

Comment: https://www.umweltbundesamt.de/api/air_data/v2/measures/json?date_from=2020-01-01&date_to=2020-01-05&time_from=1&time_to=24&component=1&scope=1

Comment: What nodes specifically do you not see?

Comment: ..the number of the nodes is not correct.

Comment: How many nodes are you expecting and how many are you actually getting?

Comment: I expect 480 nodes, but I see only 53 nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `values[2]` and `values[4]` are null for some of the stations in the JSON.  The first such station is `260`, which is the 54th station in the list.  You are attempting to parse these values as doubles, but a double can't be null, so it is throwing an exception.  My psychic powers tell me that the above code is inside a try/catch and the catch block is probably empty.  So the list is only filled with the first 53 stations before the exception is hit.

You need to fix your code so that it can deal with possible null values.  Instead of using `Convert.ToDouble()`, use [`double.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Double_TryParse_System_String_System_Double__), which will tell you if the conversion succeeded or not.  If it did not succeed, you can either discard the bad data or set a default value instead.